# Get variable value from its name as a string at runtime in C++

Tags: c++, string, parameters, format, runtime

I'm trying to reproduce **(*)** something similar to [Python `fstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-f-string), or at least [its `format` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) (and while at it, I'd like to implement something like [its "Mini-language"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)).

**(*) *N.B.*:** please note that I am aware of the existence of the [standard lib's format library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/format), as well as the existence of the [{fmt} library](https://fmt.dev/); but,

**a:** neither the g++ (11.2.1) nor the clang++ (12.0.1) that I have on my machine can compile code including `<format>`, and

**b:** I don't want to use the excellent {fmt} lib, because I'm precisely trying to do my own thing/thingy.

I'm going to use a string in input to my format object, and any number of additional arguments, like that:

```cpp
// First, some vars
std::string stef{"Stéphane"};
std::string cpp{"C++"};
int ilu3t{3000};

// Then the big deal
std::string my_fstring = badabwe::format(
    "My name is {stef}, and I love {cpp} {ilu3t} !",
    cpp,
    stef,
    ilu3t
);
// Obviously, only the 1st parameter is positional!
// my_fstring should now be:
// My name is Stephane, and I love C++ 3000 !
```

That's one of the first problem, I have to solve. I think this process is called `reflection` (please let me know if it's the case).

Next I need to handle a variable number of arguments; the 1st parameter is the only positional and mandatory one (I'm still trying to find a way to iterate over a `parameter pack`), but its a subject for another question.

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible with current C++. If you look at {fmt} you will see that is also doesn't offer this functionality in this form for the same reason.

Comment: You'll need a key-value mapping, like `std::map<string, string>{{"cpp", cpp}, {"stef", stef}, {"ilu3t", std::to_string(ilu3t)}}` and then use the map to look up the string from the key name.

Comment: if you write a function `badabwe::format(std::string foo, std::string bar, std::string baz)` then the function has no way to know the names of parameters it gets passed

Comment: @user17732522 allright... Thank you! As we say in France: “Impossible n'est pas français” ('Impossible is not frenchy"); but C++ is not french... otherwise "Paris could be or would be in a bottle" (only french speaker can understand that)..

Comment: @Eljay that's a great advice, I note that! Thank you!

Comment: its not impossible to write a function that replaces tokens in a string by parameters passed to it, just not in the way you'd like to do it

Comment: almost anything is possible if you focus on the what instead of the how ;)

Answer (score 1):

A function is not aware of name of parameters passed it. The parameter doen't even have to have a name:

```
  void foo(int x);    // name of the argument is x
  foo(42);            // 42 has no name
```

As suggested in a comment, if you want some mapping between strings (values to be replaced) and strings (their names) then you can use a map. To avoid the caller to spell out this mapping you can use a macro (usually to be avoided, but for now its the only way to get the name of a variable as a string):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using token_t = std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>;
std::string format(const std::string& tokenized,const token_t& token) {
    return "test";
}   

#define tokenize(token) { #token , to_string(token) }

using std::to_string;
std::string to_string(const std::string& str) { return str; }

int main() {
    std::string stef{"Stéphane"};
    std::string cpp{"C++"};
    int ilu3t{3000};

    std::string my_fstring = format(
        "My name is {stef}, and I love {cpp} {ilu3t} !",
        {
            tokenize(cpp),
            tokenize(stef),
            tokenize(ilu3t)
        }
    );                
}
```

I assumed that you can use `std::to_string`, though there is no `std::to_string(const std::string&)` hence I added a custom implementation.

Comment: @46305818_is_not_a_number thanks! It helps clarifying the big mess that my plan is in my head...
I'm not quite sure anymore that it is a good idea to try and implement a C++ version of Python `f-string`.